# Why is Time Complexity of Recursive Fibonacci O(2^n) and not O(n*2^n)?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, fibonacci

I understand that there are O(2^n) leaves in the recursion tree, but each path down the tree takes O(n) time to compute. So shouldn't the time complexity be O(n*2^n)?

Comment: Might be better posted on: https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: By counting the leaves you are already implicitly counting the paths.

Answer (score 0):

In this website the Time complexity is explained: [here](https://medium.com/@syedtousifahmed/fibonacci-iterative-vs-recursive-5182d7783055)

If the mathematical explanation is not enough, think about build a vector with the recursive tree options, you will get a vector with 2^n elements so the complexity of iterate it is 2^n, because you iterate once all the tree not N times all the tree.